# Concatenate and manipulate tree-like structure in bash

Tags: bash, shell, tree

Currently, I have a command that outputs data in the following format:

```
apple: banana
apple: cantaloupe
apple: durian
apple: eggplant
banana: cantaloupe
banana: durian
durian: eggplant
eggplant:
```

In other words, it's a tree-like structure in which `apple` is the root, which has children `banana` and `eggplant`, and `banana` also has sub-children `cantaloupe` and `durian`. `eggplant` has no children, yet still has a trailing colon.

I want to concatenate the output into this format:

```
apple: banana eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
durian: eggplant
eggplant:
```

Some objects may show up more than once in the output (in this case, `cantaloupe`, `durian`, and `eggplant` have multiple parent nodes). While this example doesn't have it, there may also be multiple root nodes (i.e. same breadth as `apple`).

How would I go about modifying this output? I'm using bash/shell scripting in general right now, so I was thinking `awk` would probably be the best way to handle this, but if this is better handled in Python, Ruby, Perl, or some other scripting language, I'm also open to suggestions.

Comment: Your description of a 'tree-like' structure rather sounds like DAG (Directed acyclic graph). The `make` tool is using those internaly, and `tsort` from the standard unix toolbox can do the topological sorting for you.

Comment: You know, it's funny that you bring up `make`, because I'm actually trying to build a dependency tree of `make` targets! The result below works out for me though, but thanks for the tip on `tsort` - never heard about it before.

Comment: Hey — not fair making this into a 'chameleon question'!  Ask the question you want answered.  Don't go incrementally changing it.  It is better to ask a new question if you find that your original was answered but it wasn't really what you wanted.

Comment: You're right. I'm going to get rid of that second part. If anything, that would go in its own question on here.

Comment: @CalebXu if you want to go into some visualization, look into graphviz. You don't need to build the tree yourself, just create a suitable input file with single edges, and render that with `dot`.

Comment: @liborm It certainly seems like graphviz is a tool best built for handling this, but I still feel like it' overkill for this. I'll definitely consider it for bigger projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F ': *' '{a[$1] = (a[$1]? a[$1] OFS $2 : $2)}
       END { for (i in a) print i ": " a[i] }' file
eggplant:
apple: banana cantaloupe durian eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
durian: eggplant
```

To maintain the original order:

```
awk -F ': *' '!($1 in a){b[++n]=$1} {a[$1] = (a[$1]? a[$1] OFS $2 : $2)}
   END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i] ": " a[b[i]]}' file
apple: banana cantaloupe durian eggplant
banana: cantaloupe durian
durian: eggplant
eggplant:
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! I tried this on a much bigger data set and got expected results.

Comment: Essentially the same answer as mine.  You've used a fancier field separator but have to do more work to preserve spacing.  I used a simpler field separator and just had to avoid adding spaces.  One downside to mine: if the data isn't spaced as shown (with a space after the colon), then names will be concatenated in the output.  You could simplify yours by simply adding space and new field to the list; you then don't need a space after the colon in the output.

Comment: Right, little shorter would be: `awk -F: '!($1 in a){b[++n]=$1} {a[$1]=a[$1] $2} END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i] FS a[b[i]]}' file`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '{ list[$1] = list[$1] $2 } END { for (i in list) printf "%s:%s\n", i, list[i] }'
```

Accumulate entries using the associative arrays in `awk`, building up the list.  String concatenation in `awk` is a bit weird.  At the end, print out the keys and the entries for the key.  If there's ordering required, you need to say so.

Assuming that the keys on the left should be output in the order of first appearance on the LHS of the input, then you can use this slightly more complex script:

```
awk -F: '{ if (!($1 in list)) keys[++n] = $1; list[$1] = list[$1] $2 }
         END { for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) printf "%s:%s\n", keys[j], list[keys[j]] }'
```

Comment: You can assume the input is ordered, since I'm able to `sort` it as it comes out.